# How to get a refresh token with oauth in microsoft365?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-oauth

I am trying to use microsoft365 and oauth to get an access and refresh token. According to Microsoft 365 docs, we need to use the "offline_access" scope to get a refresh token along with access token. However, The response I am getting does not contain a refresh token.

Here is the code I used:

```
    url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{}/oauth2/v2.0/token".format(tenant_id)

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }

    data = {
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

The response contains the access token like usual, but does not contain the refresh token despite using the offline_access scope. Could someone kindly tell me what the issue is?

Comment: Just a note. The scope permissions is already given to the app from the azure portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I agree with  ***@junnas***  Client Credential Flow doesn’t return refresh token as user interaction is not present.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To get the refresh token, you need to choose user interactive flows such as Auth-Code Flow.

I created an  **Azure AD Application and added API permissions**  like below:

[image]

I generated  **auth-code**  using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the  **access token and refresh token**  using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:redirectURi
code:code
```

[image]

By using the above generated refresh token, I refreshed the access token successfully like below:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:xxx
client_secret:xxx
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using client credentials flow. It does not return a refresh token because you don't need one.

Refresh tokens are involved when a user logs in to your application.
Since doing the authentication again would require that the user does the log in again, instead you get a refresh token to get new tokens.

But in the client credentials case re-authenticating is just a matter of sending the same request again.
Refresh token would add nothing to this.
Send the same request again before your token expires.